# how to change color of highcharter candlestick stockchart?

Tags: r, shiny, highcharts, candlestick-chart, r-highcharter

I am trying to build a candlestick chart with quantmod and highcharter package. Building the chart is super easy.

```
library(quantmod)
library(highcharter)

x <- getSymbols("GOOG", auto.assign = FALSE)

highchart(type = "stock") %>%
  hc_add_series(x)
```

The code above produces this chart:
[image]

I want to change the colors of the candlesticks. I want the upward changes to be in green and the downward changes to be red. I add a color argument to the `hc_add_series` as `hc_add_series(x, color = c("green", "red"))`, all the candlesticks become white. But if I provide only one color, `hc_add_series(x, color = "red")`, the downward changes becomes red. But I couldn't find a way to change the color of the upward changes.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. I need to use the `upColor` argument.

```
library(quantmod)
library(highcharter)

x <- getSymbols("GOOG", auto.assign = FALSE)

highchart(type = "stock") %>%
  hc_add_series(x, upColor = "green", color = "red")
```

This would be the solution.

Comment: You can accept your answer to mark it as the correct solution